# JavaFX и создание метода

Tags: java, javafx

Для определенных целей мне нужно создать метод, который будет вызывать диалоговое окно с пользователем ( TextInputDialog ), после ввода пользователем данных в это окно, мне нужно этот результат сохранять, т.е к примеру будет String name = МОЙ_МЕТОД и в name записывался результат, который пользователь ввел в диалоговом окне TextInputDialog. С JavaFX вроде немного разобрался, но там же все запускается в мейне через launch(args) и я не понимаю как обрабатывать результат. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее спасибо

Comment: создаете метод в контролере, сохраняете в этом же классе и строку. Потом вызываете метод через условие

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Что мешает написать такой метод, какой вам нужен? Чем вам мешает то, что всё запускается через `launch()`?